# The process "git log --pretty=format:'%H' -n 1" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds

Tags: laravel, git

The process "git log --pretty=format:'%H' -n 1" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds

На определенных страницах сайта выскакивает через раз эта ошибка. Не могу понять из-за чего. 
Например, вчера работало сегодня эта ошибка.
Это на laravel 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

git пытается получить историю коммитов. 
Первый вариант - git в фоне ждет нажатия клавиши. В этом случае либо глобально отключите это

```
git config pager.log false
```

либо в вызов добавьте ключ --no-pager

Второй вариант - возможно история раздута. В этом случае можно добавить в вызове git "--since...." чтобы не тянуть все коммиты с начала времен.

Comment: А зачем при `-n 1` гиту тянуть все коммиты?

Comment: Ваша правда. не заметил

Comment: То есть с помощью команды git config pager.log false я исправлю ошибку?